# Using stream to check if list has only specific elements permutations in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to come up a solution using streams to solve this problem and I looked up if someone has came across this but couldn't find this. 
So I have a list of three elements, let call it list1 and another list say list2 which can have different elements and can also contain duplicate items from list1.

What I want to achieve :-

1. Check if the list2 has any element which isn't in list1.
2. Check if list2 has only 2 item from list1 at a time.

For 2 - I could use set, convert list2 to set and see if list1 containsAll the set.

But I wanted to know if I can use stream here!

Eg

list1 (1,2,3) and list2 (1,1,2,2) - returns true

list1 (1,2,3) and list2 (1,1,3,3) - returns true

list1 (1,2,3) and list2 (1,1,2,2,4) -return false

I hope this makes it little clear

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static <T> boolean func(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    return list2.stream()
        .distinct()
        .map(list1::contains)
        .reduce(0,
            (result, current) -> result < 0 ? -1 : (current ? result + 1 : -1),
            (a, b) -> a < 0 || b < 0 ? -1 : a + b) == 2;
  }
```

But suggest you don't use stream for such complex logic.

Comment: Haha, yes looks scary!

Comment: It could be slightly simplified by changing the accumulator to `result < 0 || !current ? -1 : result + 1`. But it still looks scary and takes some time to understand :D

Comment: @MalteHartwig and when shorter means simpler, we can use `(a|b) < 0` instead of `a<0 || b<0` in the merge function… or even `(a,b) -> ((a|b)>>31)|(a+b)`

Comment: @Holger shorter, yes, but understanding this... it would require some extensive code comments IMO :) still awesome, though

Comment: @Holger it wasn't so much about shorter, I was trying to flatten the nested conditional. The nesting was not necessary as two of the three outcomes were the same. Those bit operators look funny, but I personally try to avoid them as not everyone (me included) understands them intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are probably not the most efficient way to tackle this problem. Nonetheless, here is another approach that has the advantage of *short-circuting* as soon as we find the third element contained or the first element not contained in `list1`:

```
public static <T> boolean func(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
{
    AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);
    return list2.stream()
                .distinct()
                .allMatch(element -> list1.contains(element) &&
                                     count.incrementAndGet() < 3)
           && count.get() == 2;
}
```

We have to "cheat" a bit, though: In order to not go through the complete stream, we have to limit the elements with the help of a counter.

The check `&& count.get() == 2` makes sure that you have exactly 2 elements that are contained in `list1`. If 0 or 1 element are also acceptable, remove that check.

Comment: This is nice and succinct :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return Optional.of(list2)
        .filter(list -> list.stream().allMatch(list1::contains))
        .map(list -> list.stream().distinct().map(list1::contains))
        .map(stream -> stream.mapToInt(x -> x ? 1 : 0))
        .map(IntStream::sum)
        .filter(sum -> sum == 2)
        .isPresent();
```

Unfortunately, you're essentially performing the same stream operation twice. Alternatively, to avoid this, collect the stream and reconvert it:

```
List<Boolean> containedInFirst = list2.stream()
        .distinct()
        .map(list1::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
return Optional.of(containedInFirst)
        .filter(list -> list.stream().allMatch(x -> x))
        .map(list -> list.stream().mapToInt(x -> x ? 1 :0))
        .map(IntStream::sum)
        .map(sum -> sum == 2)
        .filter(sum -> sum == 2)
        .isPresent();
```

You're essentially creating two tracks with the optional: the one which matches your requirements and those that don't. Any time you find something that doesn't match up, you throw it out with a filter. Anything that is still in the pipeline by the `isPresent` matches your criteria.